# Is it safe to move a LUKS encrypted partition to another system and be able to use the same passphrase?

Tags: linux, partitioning, encryption, luks

If I have a LUKS encrypted partition with a passphrase, is all the information to unlock the partition contained in the header?

Is the following correct:

The passphrase allows access to the header which contains the key that the partition was encrypted with? And if I move the entire partition to another system, and have the passphrase, will I be able to mount?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. That is correct. A LUKS volume is self contained and works as you described.

Comment: Using LVM partitions with `dd` and SSH, I successfully transferred LUKS-partition to a new machine to same sized volume. In my scenario, this was the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

While the assumptions are correct, it's probably faster to create a new LUKS device (possible with a different size, filesystem, or encryption algorithms) and copy or `rsync` the files instead of `dd`-ing the whole encrypted device or partition (well, if your filesystem is 95% full, it could be slower in fact).

You can use the same passphrase, but your master key will be different, unless you restore a LUKS header backup on the new device.
However there's no reason to keep the master key unchanged.